# How to define a variable in a foreach loop, but only when a button is clicked

Tags: php, html

I want to make an invoice, the clients are shown in a table with the foreach loop. The data is extracted from my SQL database with PDO like this:

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\App\include\dbconnect.php';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clienten WHERE verzekeraar = ?';
$stmt = $database->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION["ROL"]));
$clienten = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($clienten as $client) {
```

But now I have made a button in the table, and when it is pressed you get redirected to *make_invoice.php* and the data is converted to PDF to be printed / e-mailed etc. based on the client_ID that is in the table like this:

Polisnummer:

How do I get the `$client['clientID']` to *make_invoice.php* when this button is clicked?

```
<tr><th>Create invoice </th><td><form action='make_invoice.php' method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="aanmaken" value="Click here">
    </form>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: You already have that variable on `$client['clientID']` just add a hidden input with this value.

Comment: @Triby That did it, thank you :)

Comment: How do you choose a client from the table? I do not see any markup that shows you can pick one of the clients.

Comment: @MathCoder I can see all the clients in the database, because $clienten holds all the data in an array, and I put it an foreach loop, I can display it in the table as $client['clientID']. But I needed a button to get the data from 1 specific client to another file, so I could create an invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by adding

```
<input type="hidden" value="$client['clientID']">
```

to the form.